# Random number between 1 and 20 excluding numbers already picked

Tags: vb.net, random

I am trying to create a random number generator that runs multiple times but after each time adds the previously selected number to an array list then excluding the numbers in the array from random function.

Any ideas?

i tried this but it done it all in one line but i need it separate to call up functions using the numbers

```
        Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    TextBox1.Text = ""


    For x = 0 To 5
    Start:
        Randomize()
        intNumber = Int((20 * Rnd()) + 1)
        For y = 0 To 5
            If intNumber = arrNumber(y) Then
                GoTo Start
            End If
        Next y
        arrNumber(x) = intNumber

    Next x
    For i = 0 To 5
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & (arrNumber(i)) & " , "

    Next


End Sub
```

Comment: Please, show us what you have tried.

Comment: So what you really want is a list with 20 elements.  And you randomly pick one of them and remove it from the list.  That's called a *shuffle*.  Type "[vb.net] shuffle" in the Search box at the upper right of this page.

Comment: Looks as a school task. Please show your workings and what exactly your problem is.

Comment: I see. There are various things not too clear in that code; but, in any case, it seem that you didn't take the best approach. I have added a code showing you how to face the problem in a different way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have a sample code which you should be able to adapt to your exact requirements easily. It includes two buttons (`newRandom` and `reset`): one for generating a new random number (displayed via `MessageBox`) and the other one for deleting the list storing all the number which have appeared so far.

```
Dim alreadyPicked As List(Of Integer) = New List(Of Integer) 

Private Sub newRandom_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles newRandom.Click

    Dim curNumber As Integer
    If (alreadyPicked.Count < 20) Then
        Dim rand As Random = New Random
        Do
            curNumber = rand.Next(1, 20)
        Loop While (alreadyPicked.Contains(curNumber))
    End If


    If (curNumber > 0 AndAlso Not alreadyPicked.Contains(curNumber)) Then
        alreadyPicked.Add(curNumber)
        MessageBox.Show("The new random number is: " & curNumber.ToString())
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Error")
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub reset_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles reset.Click

    alreadyPicked = New List(Of Integer)

End Sub
```

Comment: @user3052562 You are welcome. But bear in mind that my intention was just showing you a different way to face the problem (and thus expect you to learn from this code (and improve it as much as required), not to use it blindly). Also note that I have written this answer only because you posted your code (= showed your effort) and it was clear that you needed various hints.

Comment: im having abit of trouble on another function in my project could you please take a look here [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20304209/trying-to-load-textbox-number-from-array
will be very grateful

Comment: @user3052562 Yes, I saw that (actually I did comment in this post :)). See... this is not how things work in SO (at least, with me): you cannot expect to get custom algorithms for your problems. As explained above, I wrote this code to give you a solid start to work with; not to take it blindly (what you seem to have done by looking at the code you posted in the other question). Perhaps other person can help you (most likely thinking like me: just once and I hope that you will learn from this). My recommendation (after looking at your two codes) is: learn more about the basics...

Comment: @user3052562 you seem to have serious VB.NET lacks (and programming ones in general: in the code in your other question you should have used a loop instead of 20 identical lines; any junior programmer in any language knows that) and thus I don't think that answering your question is actually helping you (and in any case is completely against what my participation in SO is expected to be; you might pay a developer to answer any doubt you have if you wish). But as said: you can wait and sooner or later someone will give you some advice; but I am done with this specific code.